# IBM composer deletes my circuit

Tags: ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit, ibm-quantum-devices

When I work on the IBM quantum composer and I switch to another circuit, my first circuit is destroyed and replaced by the second one. I thought it was a display bug, but when I restart the composer, my first circuit is actually destroyed. Does anybody know how to avoid deleting the circuit? Is it a bug?

Comment: My circuits are saved.  You have to click the little file icon on the top left.